# Is there already any functions operates on latex equations mathematically in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex

I have been thinking on editing latex equations mathematically in emacs:

1. Select current math **term**, shift it left and right, even across a "=" and changing signs. Terms are defined by "+" and "-" and other defined delimeters.

e.g. \alpha \bm{x} - 3\bm{y} = 10t, place cursor on "3" and call a function, the -3\bm{y} is selected. Call another function can change the equation to -3\bm{y}+\alpha\bm{x}=10t or \alpha \bm{x}=10t+3\bm{y}

2. Put coefficients into brackets, and even collect coefficients out.

e.g. With a function call can change 2(x+y) to (2x+2y).

3. Select current macro under cursor, copy the euqation from previous "=" or from a previous label.
4. The list goes on....

I have been using AUCTeX, CDLaTeX and RefTeX but up till now I do not know any functions already exists that can reach the effects above. So I want to ask if anyone knows an existing package in emacs can do these? If not, I am planning to elisp them myself

Comment: Emacs Calc can [interpret and produce expressions in LaTeX format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/TeX-and-LaTeX-Language-Modes.html), and can certainly do symbolic manipulation. So maybe this is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am going to explore it.